# What is the optimum way to handle broken images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

So there seems to be quiet a few ways to handle broken images on a html page. I would like to know what ways are in popular use and what ways are viewed to be best practice?

To start I've looked at some myself like:

```
function imgErr(source) {     
    source.src = /images/missing.jpg";
    source.onerror = "";
    return true;
}
<img src="test.jpg" alt="test" title="test" onerror="imgErr(this);" />
```

Pros: works everytime, the event will always be caught. User never sees broken image. Seems to work well across the browsers.
Cons: onerror tag required on each image, function imgErr(source) needs to be in the head to catch the errors, slows down the users experienced load time

```
$('img').error(function(){
  $(this).attr('src', 'missing.jpg');
});
```

Pros: very little code, works on all images without changing their markup, can be place outside of the head
Cons: can miss the error event depending on the speed of the pages onload event, slows down the users experienced load time

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $("img").each(function() {
        if (!this.complete || typeof this.naturalWidth == "undefined" || this.naturalWidth == 0) {
            var src = $(this).attr("src");
            var suffix = src.substring(src.length - 6, src.length).split('.')[0];
            suffix = suffix.charAt(suffix.length - 1);            
            $(this).attr("src", "/static/images/generic/missing_" + suffix + ".jpg");
        }
    });
});
```

Pros: Can be placed anywhere on the page, will fix the images no matter when it gets to run, doesn't slow down the users experienced load time
Cons: shows a broken image till it runs creating a poor user experience

In my situation load time is the greatest issue but I can't get the last option to work in IE properly as it changes broken and none broken images alike!

Cheers,
Denis

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One thought that does spring to mind is to create an image handler at your web server, i.e.

```
<img src="fetchimage.aspx?name=test.jpg" alt="test" title="test" />
```

Ignore the aspx, obviously it'd be replaced with whatever your preferred server scripting technology was. That handler can then deal with image names that aren't present by delivering your missing.jpg for all unknown image names.

Other than that you are stuck with the options you give as far as I can see. Any javascript that runs before the page has loaded risks not iterating over img tags not yet received and any script that waits for page ready is going to risk the user seeing broken images.

Rock->You<-Hardplace

Comment: A variation of this answer may be to let an isapi-filter/apache-mod handle requests for the common image file extensions so that you don't need to change all your img src attributes to point to your handler.

Comment: I agree with this. A generic handler would be my choice if I was adamant about fixing broken images.

Comment: This might be an option for me to look into with MVC but I had hoped I could keep it simple on the server side!

Comment: A great suggestion from @grenade, +1 for that. I believe this might also be possible on IIS but is outside of my experience. I use an image 'server' for my MVC app (in dev at the moment) which serves a 'no-image' image when appropriate but I have baked that in since the start, so easy with MVC!

Comment: and on a very large site (like 5000 pages and more), how will you find broken images?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, using the `alt` tag is enough and there's no need to add complexity to the page by checking for it every time using javascript.

Of course you need to check every once in a while that you don't have broken image. [There are tools to do it](http://home.snafu.de/tilman/xenulink.html).

Comment: Wouldn't it be great if we didn't have clients/bosses and appearance wasn't everything :D

Comment: @marcgg Disagree. There are lots of circumstances where a place-holder image can contribute to the aesthetics of a page. For example, a product catalog may contain many products for which an image has not yet been supplied. An intelligent missing image handler can then substitute a generic product image in the correct category for the product.

Comment: @grenade: we're talking about broken image. If the image is not yet supplied, it's not a broken image. To sum it up :  if(image.exists_in_the_database?) display_image else display_placeholder

Comment: @marcgg indeed. That's why we use a placeholder instead of an alt tag. What's a "broken" image if not missing?

Comment: I would have to agree with marcgg. In our site we have the application/data decide if theres an image for the listing object if it doesn't have one we show a nice coloured missing image. What I'm talking about here is where the image that is pointed to in the data doesn't actually exist.

Comment: I think that's what we're all talking about. The only point I was trying to make is that using an alt tag does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally the alt tag should just be used.  If this is vital the javascript solution really isn't ideal because it won't work if JS is turned off.  You could however do sort of server side solution.  Something in php could be done like this but would require a database or some sort of way of setting variables.

```
<?php
if($image !== ''){?> 
<?php echo '<img src="$imgsrc" alt="$imgalt" />' ?>
}
<?php else {
<?php echo '<img src="$imgmissing" alt="$imgalt" />' ?>
} ?>
<?php } ?>
```