# Replace broken image using ONLY javascript

Tags: javascript, image, d3.js

This seems a question asked a thousand times... but I've spent two days on that and haven't worked it out yet.

I've seen answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050597/what-is-the-optimum-way-to-handle-broken-images), especially the first one. But when I try to do it using only javascript, the program never waits. Even if I put the return in

```
if(image.complete) {return path;}
```

It rather exit with nothing than wait the image load.

Here's my code. I want it in purely Javascript because the return of the function is the value of the attribut of an svg:image in d3.js

```
.attr("xlink:href", function (d) {
          var imagePath = "http://xxxxx/peopleimages/" + d.num + ".jpg";
          var img = new Image();
          function onErrorHandler(image) {
              image.onerror = "";
              image.src = genericPath;
              return false;
          }
          img.onerror = onErrorHandler(this);
          img.src = imagePath;

          return img.src;
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The code should be more like this:

```
function onErrorHandler() {
    $(this).off('error', onErrorHandler);
    this.src = genericPath;
    return false;
}
$(img).on('error', onErrorHandler);
img.src = imagePath;

return img.src;
```

Comment: Excuse me but I am totally new to javascript, console says HTMLImageElement has no method 'on'

Comment: Sorry, but the return still won't wait the onErrorHandler =(

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if what you need but usually I use onload and onerror and I have no problems.  Some like that:

```
function loadImg(targetId,imgURL){
    var contenedorImgs = document.getElementById("container");
    target = document.getElementById(targetId);
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function(){
        contenedorImgs.replaceChild(img,target);
        img.id = targetId;
    };
    img.onerror = function(){
        img.src = "http://marcocavalieri.es/fotos/miniaturas/1B.jpg";
    };
    img.src = "http://dev.marcocavalieri.es/fotos/" + imgURL;
}
```

This code is an excerpt of a real code my daughter and I develop for Marco Cavalieri you can see at http://dev.marcocavalieri.es, in this case I pre-load the images because I need some fadein and fadeouts.
You can see the living excerpt example in fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/hmariod/kCRHV/1/

Bonne année et bonne santé!